# for loop doesn't reflect the change caused by setTimeout callback

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, closures

I'm learning about Angular component lifecycle. While debugging an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`, I stumbled upon this [code](https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular-33f9ffff6f10):

```
class AppComponent {
    _time;
    get time() {  return this._time; }

    constructor() {
        this._time = Date.now();

        setInterval(() => {
            this._time = Date.now();
        }, 1);
    }
}
```

When I do a lot of printing:

```
app = new AppComponent();
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    console.log(app.time);
}
```

the printed values don't change at all, although the change should be very frequent. My question is: is there a closure that keeps the `app.time` value so multiple `console.log` statements see that same value? Or if it isn't the case, why the updating is blocked?

Comment: in such a loop, nothing else happens except 1000000 console.logs ... so app.time won't update - try reading about [javascript concurrency and the event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) for a better understanding why your code behaves as it does

Comment: I'll read it now. So the loop simply blocks the callback which changes the `_time`, right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right

Comment: app.time seems asynch hence its not updating immediately ?

Comment: @MukulSharma I don't think so, just the loop block it. But it still bugs me thoug: why doesn't, or can't, the callback interrupt the loop?

Comment: @MukulSharma from what I read, the `for` block is added first (and maybe whatever block comes next?), then the callback is added. The `for` blocks runs to completion, only then the callback kicks in. There's an example in the link @Bravo commented

Comment: @MinhNghĩa  ok thank you